# Selenium RemoteWebdriver Edge does not work

Tags: selenium, grails, selenium-grid

I have my own selenium grid with different windows machines. One of this is a Windows 10 machine. Chrome and Firefox works, but I cant't get Edge to run.

My exception:

```
geb.driver.DriverCreationException: failed to create driver from callback 'script1460298173607577952326$_run_closure3@6256ac4f'
at geb.driver.CallbackDriverFactory.getDriver(CallbackDriverFactory.groovy:35)
at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver_closure3(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:85)
at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver_closure3(CachingDriverFactory.groovy)
at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory$SimpleCache.get(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:32)
at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:84)
at geb.Configuration.createDriver(Configuration.groovy:382)
at geb.Configuration.getDriver(Configuration.groovy:371)
at geb.Browser.getDriver(Browser.groovy:108)
at geb.spock.GebSpec.propertyMissing(GebSpec.groovy:60)
at specs.LomnidoBaseSpec.setupSpec(LomnidoBaseSpec.groovy:28)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities [{platform=WIN10, browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=}]
Command duration or timeout: 382 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'peter-laptop', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-85-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
```

I have installed Microsoft WebDriver on the windows machine.

My code in gebconfig.groovy

```
driver = {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.edge()
        capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10)
        new RemoteWebDriver(                    
                new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities
        )
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

On the windows machine, I had to add following parameters on startup of my node:
Dwebdriver.edge.driver="C:/selenium/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe" -browser browserName="MicrosoftEdge",platform=WIN10

Answer (score 1):

Peter

```
Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities [{platform=WIN10, browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=}]
```

is Grid's way of telling you that it didn't find any nodes that are having a browser named "MicrosoftEdge" with its platform setup as "WIN10".

You would need to go back and take another look at how you are spawning your node and see if it needs to be tweaked a bit.

To get a general overview on how to setup a grid, you can perhaps take a look at [this](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2012/01/23/setting-up-grid2-and-working-with-it/) blog post of mine.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but your blog did not help to solve my problem. I have done everything described to add the Edge to a node, but the edge browser is not registered to my hub

Comment: I need to read through that blog post. I'm trying to use selenium standalone server in a grails project and it's failing in production. Works from IntelliJ, hopefully this can solve my problem.